# Magento 2: Terms and Conditions Validation issue

Tags: magento2, validation, terms-and-conditions

I am working with Magento 2.1.0. I have enabled 'Terms and conditions' on site and added 2 conditions one for 'Terms and conditions' and other for 'Replacement Policy'. It displayed both in checkout page correctly, but validation is done only for the first check-box. Not considering the second one. If first check-box is checked. We will be able to place the order.

I have found out that it is the issue with the Magento 2. How can I fix this issue? Please help.

Comment: Did you got any solution??

Answer (score 5):

We have face the same issue(terms and conditions not validating) in our system, and change the below mentioned code. Now working properly.

**File Path:**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/view/frontend/web/js/model/agreement-validator.js

**Change the below code:**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'mage/validation'
    ],
    function ($) {
        'use strict';
        var checkoutConfig = window.checkoutConfig,
            agreementsConfig = checkoutConfig ? checkoutConfig.checkoutAgreements : {};

        var agreementsInputPath = '.payment-method._active div.checkout-agreements input';

        return {
            /**
             * Validate checkout agreements
             *
             * @returns {boolean}
             */
            validate: function() {
                var noError = true;
                if (!agreementsConfig.isEnabled || $(agreementsInputPath).length == 0) {
                    return noError;
                }

                $('.payment-method:not(._active) div.checkout-agreements input')
                    .prop('checked', false)
                    .removeClass('mage-error')
                    .siblings('.mage-error[generated="true"]').remove();

                $(agreementsInputPath).each(function() {
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');

                    var result = $('#co-payment-form').validate({
                        errorClass: 'mage-error',
                        errorElement: 'div',
                        meta: 'validate',
                        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                            var errorPlacement = element;
                            if (element.is(':checkbox') || element.is(':radio')) {
                                errorPlacement = element.siblings('label').last();
                            }
                            errorPlacement.after(error);
                        }
                    }).element(agreementsInputPath + '[name="' + name + '"]');

                    if (!result) {
                        noError = false;
                    }
                });

                return noError;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**After changed the code you will following command:**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: hey @Sankar_k, which magento version did you use? we face the same problem with M2.1.5 - tried your solution but doesn't work. I Created the Magento_CheckoutAgreements module in our theme and applied the mentioned edits. Any idear?

Comment: Hi  @Florin P. We have used the M2.1.4 shop system. But We have checked same in M2.1.5 and M2.1.6, and found that everything working properly. Please check the below mentioned file path: (<root>/pub/static/frontend/Magento/{themes}/{language}/Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/model/agreement-validator.js. ). In this files also updated. And clear the shop cache and browser cache.

Comment: nope, the file is not updated, i can do it manually but its not the right way. what i dont understand is why its not generated from the new file edited in app/design/frontend/Theme/default/Magento_CheckoutAgreements/view/frontend/web/js/model/agreement-validator.js

Comment: Before run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` comment in terminal, rewrite the folder name.  **Example:** you have same update the frontend files. Rewrite the below folder: **pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US** to **pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US_backup**

Comment: I got it, the problem was the path to the js file

Comment: This problem still persists in Magento 2.1.9. I can confirm that this fix still works. Just copy the js file to your theme (`app/design/frontend/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/Magento_CheckoutAgreements/web/js/model/agreement-validator.js`) and edit it.

Comment: @GielBerkers, i have used in the same path as suggested, but still the issue exists.

Comment: I've only one checkbox(Terms and conditions), the first one itself not working, even I checked the box it shows me validation fail

Comment: @Sankar_k, I have two terms and conditions, I was used same code but issue is still exist into 2.1.9.

Comment: @RaviDudhara Please use the above code

Answer (score 2):

You stumbled upon a bug in Magento 2.1.x. There's currently a bug report on Github regarding it: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5632

Answer (score 1):

Bug Reported for the same on git hub for 2.1.X.

Refer this link -  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5632